# React-select-plus Option Groups drop down async issue

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-select

I am using React-Select Plus control for binding drop down in React. I have finding issue when binding async option group drop down in React.
Here My Code :

```js
  getSearch = (input) => {
    if (!input) {
      return Promise.resolve({ options: [] });
    }
    const newstate = this.state;
    this.setState({ newstate });

    newstate.loadingtext = 'Searching...';
    const searchLocation = Object.assign({}, cookie.load('cLocation'));
    searchLocation.searchText = input;
    searchLocation.isBusiness = true;
    const myInit = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(searchLocation),
    };
    return fetch(`url/methodname`, myInit)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => [{ value: json.data, label: json.data }]);
  }
    gotoSearch = (value) => {
    window.open(value.html_url);
  }
```

```html
<Select.Async
              onChange={this.onChange}
              onValueClick={this.gotoSearch}
              valueKey="placeID"
              labelKey="cityState"
              loadOptions={this.getSearch}
              value={this.state.value}
              loadingPlaceholder={this.state.loadingtext}
              noResultsText="No results found"
              placeholder="Name, City, Zip"
              options={ops}
            />
```

I refer this URL : http://github.hubspot.com/react-select-plus/

please help me.

Comment: whats not working? notice that your snippet isn't really working

Comment: Can't you just use `onChange={this.onChangeö.bind(this)}`? Please explain a bit better what exactly is not working

Comment: When I implement option group with dynamically url that not working can you please provide   examples  the async option with option groups.

Comment: why are you using both `options` and `loadOptions`? in `Select.Async` i think you should use only the `loadOptions` prop. see here https://github.com/HubSpot/react-select-plus#async-options-with-promises